# An error occurred while installing gitlab-pygments.rb (0.3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, gitlab, nas, qnap

I've got problem with my gitlab instalation on NAS QNAP TS-112. When i try do this :

bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres aws

I get an error

Using gitlab-grack 1.0.1

Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /share/HDA_DATA/homes/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/cache/gitlab-pygments.rb-0.3.2.gem. It may be corrupted.
An error occurred while installing gitlab-pygments.rb (0.3.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install gitlab-pygments.rb -v '0.3.2'` succeeds before bundling.

How i can fix this error.

Comment: Can you make `gem install gitlab-pygments.rb -v '0.3.2'` succeed, and then use it on a test script? If not, the problem is not gitlab related and you should see what causes that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I could install but then was the same error.
The solution was > sudo -i -u git